# Company / Product Info Directory Website - Copyright Laws

Tags: links, legal, copyright, database, trademark

I want to create a large business directory website , which would allow a user (buyer) to search, filter and identify suitable products.

I would require company logos and use of product names (TM,CopyRight) for my website to look professional.

As an example… 
If my business directory (website) was considering the Food & Drink Industry

- Level 0  -  Category  -  Soft Drinks, Soft Drinks
- Level 1  -  Company  -  Coca Cola Company, PepsiCo
- Level 2  -  Product  -  Fanta Orange, Pepsi Max
- Level 3  -  AdditionalInfo  -  High Sugar, Zero Sugar

If my user filtered the directory and chose Fanta Orange.  There would be a link which would take the user to that site.

My Question...
Do I require permission to use companies logos and titles?  Some of these companies are large global organisations and contacting the right person may prove difficult.
On another note…
Is there a similar way to operate this like GlassDoor does?

Comment: You asked the same sort of question about the same thing twice.  If you are happy to accept some random internet person's opinion on copyright instead of getting legal advice, you deserve the outcome.

Comment: @Steve this version of the question looks much better to me.  It is clearly about their own website now.   We can't give legal advice (from a lawyer) here, but we can answer legal questions  with best practices for webmasters.   See [Legal Questions Revisited](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/710/legal-questions-revisited) on meta.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for getting back in touch.
@Steve, who says that I'm happy to accept some random persons answer?  I'm investigating a new idea with which I don't have much experience.
I am purely looking for some information so I can make a sensible decision on how to proceed as I only thought of this yesterday.
You're right I could've worded my 1st question better and shouldn't have brought up the Glassdoor in my 1st question.  I know StackExchange doesn't like 2 q's in one post.
My 2nd question is more about how GlassDoor operated as a company thanks.